# how to select stream for mapping

Tags: ffmpeg

here's the stream info

```
  Program 0
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 660144
    Stream #0:0(en): Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      comment         : English
    Stream #0:1: Data: timed_id3 (ID3  / 0x20334449)
    Stream #0:2(hi): Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp
    Metadata:
      comment         : Hindi
    Stream #0:3: Data: timed_id3 (ID3  / 0x20334449)
    Stream #0:4(bn): Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp
    Metadata:
      comment         : Bengali
    Stream #0:5: Data: timed_id3 (ID3  / 0x20334449)
    Stream #0:6(mr): Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp
    Metadata:
      comment         : Marathi
    Stream #0:7: Data: timed_id3 (ID3  / 0x20334449)
    Stream #0:8: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p, 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 660144
    Stream #0:9: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 660144
    Stream #0:10: Data: timed_id3 (ID3  / 0x20334449)
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 660144
  Program 1
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 944962
    Stream #0:0(en): Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      comment         : English
    Stream #0:1: Data: timed_id3 (ID3  / 0x20334449)
    Stream #0:2(hi): Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp
    Metadata:
      comment         : Hindi
    Stream #0:3: Data: timed_id3 (ID3  / 0x20334449)
    Stream #0:4(bn): Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp
    Metadata:
      comment         : Bengali
    Stream #0:5: Data: timed_id3 (ID3  / 0x20334449)
    Stream #0:6(mr): Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp
    Metadata:
      comment         : Marathi
    Stream #0:7: Data: timed_id3 (ID3  / 0x20334449)
    Stream #0:11: Video: h264 (Main) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p, 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 944962
    Stream #0:12: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 944962
    Stream #0:13: Data: timed_id3 (ID3  / 0x20334449)
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 944962
```

i wish to map 0:11 and 0:2 from Program 1. Probably i will need p:program_id[:stream_index].

here's what i tried but it maps 0:0 twice from Program 0 whenever a command succeeds executing.

```
ffmpeg -i "https://cdnapisec.kaltura.com/p/1982551/sp/198255100/playManifest/protocol/https/entryId/0_eyx5tw99/format/applehttp/defaultAudioLang/English/tags/tv_hd/f/a.m3u8" -map p:1:#0:11 -map p:1:#0:2 -c copy video101.ts
ffmpeg -i "https://cdnapisec.kaltura.com/p/1982551/sp/198255100/playManifest/protocol/https/entryId/0_eyx5tw99/format/applehttp/defaultAudioLang/English/tags/tv_hd/f/a.m3u8" -map p:1:#11 -map p:1:#2 -c copy video101.ts
ffmpeg -i "https://cdnapisec.kaltura.com/p/1982551/sp/198255100/playManifest/protocol/https/entryId/0_eyx5tw99/format/applehttp/defaultAudioLang/English/tags/tv_hd/f/a.m3u8" -map p:1:[0:11] -map p:1:[0:2] -c copy video101.ts
ffmpeg -i "https://cdnapisec.kaltura.com/p/1982551/sp/198255100/playManifest/protocol/https/entryId/0_eyx5tw99/format/applehttp/defaultAudioLang/English/tags/tv_hd/f/a.m3u8" -map p:1:[:11] -map p:1:[:2] -c copy video101.ts
ffmpeg -i "https://cdnapisec.kaltura.com/p/1982551/sp/198255100/playManifest/protocol/https/entryId/0_eyx5tw99/format/applehttp/defaultAudioLang/English/tags/tv_hd/f/a.m3u8" -map p:Program 1:[:11] -map p:Program 1:[:2] -c copy video101.ts
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost there. It's

```
... -map p:1:8 -map p:1:2 -c copy video101.ts
```

The stream id refers to the stream position in the program (starting with 0)

In this particular case, you can also use absolute stream ids, since streams are relisted in different programs but refer to the same underlying stream.

```
... -map 0:11 -map 0:2 -c copy video101.ts
```

Comment: i get this error  `Stream map 'p:1:11' matches no streams.  
To ignore this, add a trailing '?' to the map.`

Comment: See new commands

Comment: yes it works. tqvm.